# How to solve 404 permalink errors on nginx server

Tags: php, permalinks, 404-error, nginx

I can't solve this issue. I tried everything I found over the web. I first tried configuring my nginx.conf following the example on codex with no success.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx

I found that many users encounter this issue but the most popular fix is this:

```
    location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
```

I still get 404 for all pages. This only happens if I don't use the Plain setting in permalinks structure.

Any ideas on how can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: This is way too little information. Probably there is some conflict with a plugin. Disable them all, see if the problem is still there. Then switch them on one by one and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of debugging, I can't say exactly what the problem was, however disabling all the plugin solved the issue. It wasn't one particular plugin, I then re-enabled all of them and everything was fine. Thank you for your interest!